# What is this white dashed line across the Thames in Google Maps?

Tags: london, rivers, google-maps

What is this white dashed line (circled) across the Thames in Google Maps?

Is it possibly the site of the old London Bridge?  But what would be the use of that on a modern travel map?

[image: Thames]

Comment: If you look closely you’ll notice that it extends on both banks. It’s just more visible against the blue background of the Thames.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

OpenStreetMap has the same feature and it says it's `Northern Line (Bank Branch)` - of the subway I suppose.

It is clearly visible and marked on https://openrailwaymap.org/

[image: Open Railway Map of Tower Bridge]

Comment: [Definitely part of the Underground.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_line)  The "Bank Branch" refers to the fact that this line splits into two as it passes through central London, with a parallel branch going through Charing Cross.

Comment: Note that  the other tunnel is part of the City and South London Railway, a predecessor of the current tube network. It is now disused.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I don't why that makes it called the "Bank" branch? It isn't running parallel to the bank. Are there banks in Charing Cross? Or is it turning, and therefore banking?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-:  the line passes though [Bank Station](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_and_Monument_stations), named for its proximity to the Bank of England.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert So it doesn't have to do with the fact it splits in two? ty tho

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-:  I don't think so (though I welcome corrections from people who know better).  I think it's just that the line splits into two so that it can serve two major stations in the London transport system, which happen have the names "Bank" and "Charing Cross" respectively.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: the two branches join at Camden Town, not Euston. They do both pass through Euston - though on separate pairs of platforms.

Comment: @alamar: to nitpick: in British English, "subway" normally refers to a foot tunnel under a street. In this instance, this tunnel is part of the London Underground network, so would be referred to as an Underground line.

Comment: The Northern Line of the London Underground splits in two at Kennington; a western branch goes via Charing Cross to Euston; an eastern branch goes via Bank also to Euston, from where the two branches run side by side to Camden Town, where they join. The Bank branch is closed between Moorgate and Kennington for 17 weeks (planned) from 15 January 2022 for renovation of Bank station and realignment of the tracks there. To help passengers inconvenienced, a new bus route, the 733 from Oval into the City runs every 7-8 minutes on weekdays.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Glasgow would beg to differ.